# How to disable Ctrl + Alt + Function key combinations on Debian?

Tags: debian, gnome

How do I disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (for <kbd>F1</kbd> through  <kbd>F12</kbd> ) buttons?

How can I configure Debian("Squeeze") so that nothing happens when the user presses those keys?

I'm using Gnome as the default desktop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This requires some manual X11 server configuration.  Look in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`; if it doesn't exist, you'll need to create it with the following contents:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
  Option "DontVTSwitch" "on"
EndSection
```

If it *does* exist, look for a `Section "ServerFlags"` and add the `Option` line above to it; if there isn't one, append the above lines to the file.

Comment: What can I do if, for some reason, I want only to disable Ctrl + Alt + F11?